# Where to get the Lagoona Compiler and Specification?

Tags: programming-languages, components

The Lagoona programming language is supposed to naturally and fully support Component Oriented Programming (and DbC) according to: [this article](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~franz/Site/pubs-pdf/ICS-TR-03-22.pdf) and is implemented in .Net; but I didn't find the compiler, specification nor examples of code for it. Does anyone know where/how to get any/all of those (compiler, specification or code examples)?

Comment: I didn't have to, I missed a part in his (Petere Hans) thesis where he mentioned the actual name of the .Net implementation for it. I'll post my answer in 1 hour. Good tip though :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the .Net implementation, its called **Lava** and there's a "Programming Environment" for it called **LavaPE**; the two go hand in hand, the LavaPE is synonymous with Lava; which is what Jeff Atwood says in this [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/its-the-ide-dummy.html) that would happen with future languages. I wonder if it'll ever get to mainstream, maybe in a decade, we'll see.